# Read XML data and sort into list based on conditions

Tags: c#, xml, list, sorting

Hi this is my second question about a little project I am trying to complete, the first question was based on matching some data in two text files, into a pair of lists to compare. now I want to sort some data I have received from a restful API via HTTP get against the list from one of the list's from the first question.

this is a snipit of the text file

```
C1903:009030           COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SE   0030COM
C1904:009040           COMMERCIAL BREAK - 40 SE   0040COM
C1918:009240           COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN   0240CO
```

here is a snipit of the XML data

```
<RCSZettaAPIResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://rcsworks.com">
    <ResponseType>Success</ResponseType>
    <SyncCounter>1285121525</SyncCounter>
    <DataObject i:type="StationScheduleLog">
        <Date>2017-10-04T00:00:00</Date>
        <HourGroupCollection>
            <HourGroup>
                <Hour>19</Hour>
                <LogEventCollection>
                    <LogEvent>
                        <Chain>Segue</Chain>
                        <DisplayText>ExactTimeMarker - Reset : 00:00:00</DisplayText>
                        <ExactTimeMarkerEvent>
                            <Type>Reset</Type>
                        </ExactTimeMarkerEvent>
                        <StatusCode>Ready</StatusCode>
                        <Type>ExactTimeMarker</Type>
                        <UUID>d67afec1-59a3-e711-80ef-308d99b21a00</UUID>
                        <VerifyID></VerifyID>
                    </LogEvent>
                    <LogEvent>
                        <Chain>Stop</Chain>
                        <CommentEvent>
                            <Duration>PT3M</Duration>
                            <Text>Note: 3 Min Eagle News Bulletin</Text>
                        </CommentEvent>
                        <DisplayText>Comment - Note: 3 Min  News Bulletin</DisplayText>
                        <StatusCode>Ready</StatusCode>
                        <Type>Comment</Type>
                        <UUID>d77afec1-59a3-e711-80ef-308d99b21a00</UUID>
                        <VerifyID></VerifyID>
                    </LogEvent>
                    <LogEvent>
                        <Chain>Segue</Chain>
                        <DisplayText>ExactTimeMarker - Hit : 00:03:00</DisplayText>
                        <ExactTimeMarkerEvent>
                            <Time>PT3M</Time>
                            <Type>Hit</Type>
                        </ExactTimeMarkerEvent>
                        <StatusCode>Ready</StatusCode>
                        <Type>ExactTimeMarker</Type>
                        <UUID>d87afec1-59a3-e711-80ef-308d99b21a00</UUID>
                        <VerifyID></VerifyID>
                    </LogEvent>
                    <LogEvent>
                        <Chain>Segue</Chain>
                        <DisplayText>Spot Block</DisplayText>
                        <SpotBlockEvent>
                            <LogEventCollection>
                                <LogEvent>
                                    <AssetEvent>
                                        <EffectiveTransitions>
                                            <Duration>PT30.41S</Duration>
                                            <Runtime>PT30S</Runtime>
                                            <Segue>PT30S</Segue>
                                            <TrimIn>PT0S</TrimIn>
                                            <TrimOut>PT30.41S</TrimOut>
                                        </EffectiveTransitions>
                                        <Type>Spot</Type>
                                        <UUID>e2a39f0b-647b-4308-b85d-3f38affd2251</UUID>
                                    </AssetEvent>
                                    <Chain>Segue</Chain>
                                    <DisplayText>COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )</DisplayText>
                                    <EditCode>FlatFileInsert</EditCode>
                                    <StatusCode>Ready</StatusCode>
                                    <Type>Asset</Type>
                                    <UUID>ff4d423b-c79b-440c-bb98-e938871279dc</UUID>
                                    <VerifyID></VerifyID>
                                </LogEvent>
                            </LogEventCollection>
                            <OverrideSplitMode>Monitor</OverrideSplitMode>
                        </SpotBlockEvent>
                        <StatusCode>Ready</StatusCode>
                        <Type>SpotBlock</Type>
                        <UUID>d97afec1-59a3-e711-80ef-308d99b21a00</UUID>
                        <VerifyID></VerifyID>
                    </LogEvent>
```

I need to check the date tag `<Date>2017-10-04T00:00:00</Date>` and if the correct date check the first break from the log file `C1903` (thats 7.03pm) that they match with the hour tag `<Hour>19</Hour>` and the minuets are marked by the exact time marker at

```
                        <ExactTimeMarkerEvent>
                            <Time>PT3M</Time>
                            <Type>Hit</Type>
                        </ExactTimeMarkerEvent>
```

Denoted by the PT3M data in the Exact time tag, and then match up the length of the break `0030COM` (30 Seconds) matches the time of the break in the xml `<Runtime>PT30S</Runtime>` inside the `<Type>SpotBlock</Type>` element.

if these don't match then i need to notify the user with the mismatch.

I am way outside my skill set but loving the challenge. I just don't know how to go about it so any help guidance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Simon

EDIT Adding to this with the edits from jdweng

```
private void btnGetLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
            var client = new RestClient("http://" + tbZettaAPIServer.Text + ":3139");

            var request = new RestRequest("1.0/{id}/{stuuid}/{date}?hourFrom={startHour}&hourTo={endHour}", Method.GET);
            //request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
            // replaces matching token in request.Resource
            request.AddUrlSegment("id", "StationScheduleLog"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource
            request.AddUrlSegment("stuuid", tbStationUUID.Text);
            request.AddUrlSegment("date", xmlDate);
            request.AddUrlSegment("startHour", "19");
            request.AddUrlSegment("endHour", "20");

            // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
            request.AddHeader("APIKEY", tbZettaAPIKey.Text);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + zettaUsernameBase64);
            //request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic c3VwZXJ2aXNvcjo=");

            // replaces matching token in request.Resource
            //request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); 

            // easy async support
            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => 
            {
                //tbXMLLog.Text = (response.Content);
                xmlResponce = (response.Content);

            });
            if (xmlResponce != null)
            {
                //XDocument zettaXML = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponce);
                XDocument zettaXML = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponce);
                XElement root = zettaXML.Root;
                XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

                var results = root.Descendants(ns + "DataObject").Select(x => new {
                    date = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "Date"),
                    hour = (int)x.Descendants(ns + "Hour").FirstOrDefault(),
                    time = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Time").FirstOrDefault(),
                    runtime = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Runtime").FirstOrDefault(),
                    displayText = x.Descendants(ns + "LogEvent").Where(y => (y.Element(ns + "AssetEvent") != null) && (y.Descendants(ns + "Runtime").Any())).Select(y => (string)y.Descendants(ns + "DisplayText").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList();


            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you used `XDocument` or `XPath`? These would be the main objects you'd used to query the XML data and perform any sorting you need on the nodes

Comment: I have used `XDocument` to store the date in `zettaXML` like this `XDocument zettaXML = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponce);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the four tags (plus the display text) from the file in the code below using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://pastebin.com/raw/Ch1BeS0k";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = root.Descendants(ns + "DataObject").Select(x => new
            {
                date = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "Date"),
                hour = (int)x.Descendants(ns + "Hour").FirstOrDefault(),
                time = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Time").FirstOrDefault(),
                runtime = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Runtime").FirstOrDefault(),
                displayText = x.Descendants(ns + "LogEvent").Where(y => (y.Element(ns + "AssetEvent") != null) && (y.Descendants(ns + "Runtime").Any())).Select(y => (string)y.Descendants(ns + "DisplayText").FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The code below gets all the log events

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://pastebin.com/raw/Ch1BeS0k";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = root.Descendants(ns + "DataObject").Select(dataObject => new
            {
                hourGroups = dataObject.Descendants(ns + "HourGroup").Select(hourGroup => new
                {
                    logEvents = hourGroup.Descendants(ns + "LogEvent").Select(logEvent => new
                    {
                        date = (DateTime)dataObject.Element(ns + "Date"),
                        hour = (int)hourGroup.Element(ns + "Hour"),
                        time = (string)logEvent.Descendants(ns + "Time").FirstOrDefault(),
                        runtime = (string)logEvent.Descendants(ns + "Runtime").FirstOrDefault(),
                        displayText = (logEvent.Element(ns + "AssetEvent") != null) && (logEvent.Descendants(ns + "Runtime").Any()) ? (string)logEvent.Descendants(ns + "DisplayText").FirstOrDefault() : string.Empty
                    }).ToList()
                }).SelectMany(x => x.logEvents)
            }).SelectMany(x => x.hourGroups).ToList();

            int minute = 0;
            string minutePattern = @"PT(?'minutes'\d+)M";
            string timespanPattern = @"\(\s*(?'timespan'[^\s]+)\s+\)";
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (result.time != null)
                {
                    minute = int.Parse(Regex.Match(result.time, minutePattern).Groups["minutes"].Value);
                }
                if (result.displayText.Contains("COMMERCIAL BREAK"))
                {
                    string timeSpanStr = Regex.Match(result.displayText, timespanPattern).Groups["timespan"].Value;
                    DateTime timeSpan = DateTime.ParseExact(timeSpanStr, "mm:ss.f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    Console.WriteLine("C{0}{1}:0{2}{3}       {4}", result.hour.ToString("00"), minute.ToString("00"), (result.hour % 12).ToString("00"),timeSpan.ToString("mmss"), result.displayText);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output

```
C1903:0070030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C1904:0070030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C1918:0070250       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 50 SEC ( 02:50.0 )
C1927:0070230       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 30 SEC ( 02:30.1 )
C1935:0070030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C1946:0070030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C1947:0070240       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 40 SEC ( 02:40.1 )
C1957:0070250       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 50 SEC ( 02:50.0 )
C2003:0080030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C2004:0080030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C2018:0080240       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 40 SEC ( 02:40.1 )
C2027:0080230       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 30 SEC ( 02:30.1 )
C2030:0080030       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 30 SEC ( 00:30.4 )
C2047:0080220       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 20 SEC ( 02:20.1 )
C2057:0080220       COMMERCIAL BREAK - 2 MIN 20 SEC ( 02:20.1 )
```

Comment: Hi jdweng, I have implemented it in a button press for testing, it only checks the first line so i guess i need to loop it? and how do i know which list it is going into, i am not a trained coder just poking about for fun and the odd job to make my work life easier.  I cant paste below the code so will add to the original question. thanks Simon

Comment: results is a list so you need to put into foreach(var dataObject in results){your code here}.  Then compare each result with your text file.

Comment: there seems to be only one result in there so nothing to loop through

Comment: I wasn't sure since you said you posted a snipit of the xml.  Wrote the XML so just in case you had multiples it would still work.  Do you know how to take results and reformat as needed?

Comment: maybe, i am kinda finding my way through it, kinda!! i guess i cant learn a language with out a problem to solve, so i have been muddling through using stack and google!!!,

Comment: Great!!!  Best way of learning is to solve a problem.  I help if you can't find answers.  You can use time.Substring() to extract pieces of a string.  Or use Regex which is much more difficult to use and shouldn't be needed.

Comment: So i am confused how would i loop through the xml to fill the List?

Comment: You don't need to.  The xml file has only one item in results.  If there were more than one DataObject element than the linq I wrote would of greater a list.

Comment: Replacing the last ToList() in my code with FirstOrDefault() will give a single item that may make it easier for you to use.

Comment: I don't really understand, the list has only one item in it but the 2 hour XML document has 15 breaks in the 2 hour period. so i dont understand why it only has one break in the list?

Comment: My code breaks the list on the element "DataObject".  Where are the 15 breaks occurring?

Comment: is it easier if i post the whole XML somewhere? it's at https://pastebin.com/Ch1BeS0k if that helps

Comment: I updated code to get entire xml from the URL.  Also change List() to FirstOrDefault().  The XML has one DataObject tag with two HourGroup tags and multiple LogEvent tags.  The first LogEvent is a reset while the rest have different structures.  Some have ExactTimeMarkerEvent tag while others have Runtime tag.  My code only gets the first of each of the types you requested.  I can get arrays of each type, but I don't know how to associate ExactTimeMarkerEvents with the RunTimeEvents because they are in different Runtime tags.  I could come up with a method, but not sure it is what you need.

Comment: I now see the 15 breaks are the RunTimeEvents with "Commercial Break".  If you need all 15 I recommend you use the 2nd solution I posted above.  The filter for results with "Commercial Break".  The only issue I see is these objects do not contain the "time" property, but do have date, hour, runtime, and time in the display text.

Comment: Hay @jdweng i have been away but back on Friday, thanks so much for your help i will have a look on Friday.